# libcurl memory error while sending email via smtp

Tags: c, email, curl, smtp, libcurl

i´m encountering a strange problem.

I have developed a library to interact with huawei usb sticks. Within this library i want to read out some information from the stick and send those information in an email. For this i use the curl library for C.

I have developed my program unter MAX OS X.9 and there it has worked perfectly.

But i want to use my code on a raspberry pi, using a debian based OS (raspian).

But here i encounter memory error while executing the program:

```
Start sending message...
* About to connect() to XXXXXXX.kasserver.com port 587 (#0)
*   Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
* connected
* Connected to XXXXXXX.kasserver.com (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 587 (#0)
* SMTP 0x1ec1d88 state change from STOP to SERVERGREET
< 220 dd7300.kasserver.com ESMTP
> EHLO XXX
* SMTP 0x1ec1d88 state change from SERVERGREET to EHLO
< 250-XXX.kasserver.com
< 250-PIPELINING
< 250-SIZE 102400000
< 250-VRFY
< 250-ETRN
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
< 250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250 DSN
> STARTTLS
* SMTP 0x1ec1d88 state change from EHLO to STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
*** glibc detected *** ./test2: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x01ec5db8 ***
Aborted
```

The most strange thing is, that i can compile and run the example code from the curl website withour any problems:

[curl smtp-tsl example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html)

My code does not differ much from the example. For debugging, i used the example string array as well as the same configurations. My email text, which is passed through the parameters of the function are not used at the moment:

```
char *payload_text[] = {
  "Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
  "To: " mail_to "\r\n",
  "From: " mail_from "(Example User)\r\n",
  //"Cc: " CC "(Another example User)\r\n",
  //"Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
  "Subject: SMTP SSL example message\r\n",
  "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
  "The body of the message starts here.\r\n",
  "\r\n",
  "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
  "Check RFC5322.\r\n",
  NULL
};

char **payLoadSMTP  = NULL;

struct upload_status {
    int lines_read;
};

/**
 *  helper function for curl email send process
 *
 *  @param ptr   pointer to target structure for curl
 *  @param size  size of source
 *  @param nmemb not quite clear
 *  @param userp pointer to source
 *
 *  @return size_t length of data
 */
/*******************************************************/
static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
/*******************************************************/
{
    struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
    const char *data;
    printf("size: %i, nmemb: %i \n", size, nmemb);
    if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
        return 0;
    }

    data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];
    //data = payLoadSMTP[upload_ctx->lines_read];

    if(data) {
        size_t len = strlen(data);
        memcpy(ptr, data, len);
        printf("data[%i]: %s\n", upload_ctx->lines_read, data);
        upload_ctx->lines_read++;

        return len;

    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 *  send email with before created payload char array
 *
 *  @param payloadText array over strings
 *
 *  @return true, if playload was correct; falso if payload was empty
 */
/*******************************************************/
bool sendEmail(char **payloadText)
/*******************************************************/
{

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
    struct upload_status upload_ctx;

    upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

    payLoadSMTP = payloadText;


    if(payLoadSMTP == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        /* Set username and password */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, mail_user);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, mail_pwd);

        /* This is the URL for your mailserver. Note the use of port 587 here,
         * instead of the normal SMTP port (25). Port 587 is commonly used for
         * secure mail submission (see RFC4403), but you should use whatever
         * matches your server configuration. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, mail_url);

        /* In this example, we'll start with a plain text connection, and upgrade
         * to Transport Layer Security (TLS) using the STARTTLS command. Be careful
         * of using CURLUSESSL_TRY here, because if TLS upgrade fails, the transfer
         * will continue anyway - see the security discussion in the libcurl
         * tutorial for more details. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);

        /* If your server doesn't have a valid certificate, then you can disable
         * part of the Transport Layer Security protection by setting the
         * CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST options to 0 (false).
         *   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
         *   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
         * That is, in general, a bad idea. It is still better than sending your
         * authentication details in plain text though.
         * Instead, you should get the issuer certificate (or the host certificate
         * if the certificate is self-signed) and add it to the set of certificates
         * that are known to libcurl using CURLOPT_CAINFO and/or CURLOPT_CAPATH. See
         * docs/SSLCERTS for more information. */


        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt");
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/etc/ssl/certs/");

        /* Note that this option isn't strictly required, omitting it will result in
         * libcurl sending the MAIL FROM command with empty sender data. All
         * autoresponses should have an empty reverse-path, and should be directed
         * to the address in the reverse-path which triggered them. Otherwise, they
         * could cause an endless loop. See RFC 5321 Section 4.5.5 for more details.
         */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, mail_from);

        /* Add two recipients, in this particular case they correspond to the
         * To: and Cc: addressees in the header, but they could be any kind of
         * recipient. */
         recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, mail_to);
        //recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, CC);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

         /* We're using a callback function to specify the payload (the headers and
         * body of the message). You could just use the CURLOPT_READDATA option to
         * specify a FILE pointer to read from. */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

        /* Since the traffic will be encrypted, it is very useful to turn on debug
         * information within libcurl to see what is happening during the transfer.
         */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        printf("\nStart sending message...\n");
        /* Send the message */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        printf("...Finished sending message.\n");

        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        printf("recipients cleanup\n");
        /* Free the list of recipients */
        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

        printf("curl cleanup\n");
        /* Always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);



        printf("cleanup finished\n");
        payLoadSMTP = NULL;

        return true;
    }


    return false;

}
```

The parameters for username, password, url etc. are defines als #define constants.

Doe´s anyone has an idea for my problem?

Comment: You can do remote debugging with [gdbserver](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_130.html). Try that do see if it's a problem in your code or not.

Comment: Not sure but check is it necessary to set payLoadSMTP to NULL as it is been assigned to same value of payloadText. It seems your code is trying to do double delete or rather delete an already deleted memory address

Comment: @Prakash payLoadSMTP is not used here, i only use the static string array from the basic example code.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg what is the advantage from gdbserver? As far as i know i need the sources and symbols for libcurl to debug within the curl_easy_perform function where the error occurs. I was wondering if it could be some problem with the certificates because this is hat is displayed next in the original example code.

Comment: @solick The thing is that you need to determine that it actually is a problem in libcurl, and not in your code. Once you determine that it's not your code you can give a bug-report to the libcurl project, and state with certainty that it's a bug in libcurl.